# How to show success or failure message in angular?

Tags: html, angular, webapi

user.component.html

```
<form #ff="ngForm">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="User Name" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.fname"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="age" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.age"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.sex"/> Male<br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.sex"/> Female<br/><br/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" (click)="createUserData(ff.value)">
</form>
```

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../service/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private us:UserService) { }

  user:  any;
  selectedUser:  any  = {fname:null, age:  null, sex: null};

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createUserData(ff){
    this.us.createform(ff).subscribe((user:any)=>{
      console.log("Success register");
    });
  }
}
```

I am new in angular and I am trying to insert form data in database using web API to mysqli which is working fine. Now, I want to show success or failure message in my `user.component.html` page. I want when I click on submit button the page reload and show `success or failure` message. So, How can I do this please help me.

Thank you

Comment: when you submit form-data to api, then api gives results back as success or failure . and based on this, you can assign template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reload the page. You can choose to navigate to another component/page, or you can show a Popup dialog or you could render ad different content.
here a very simple example in order to render a different content:

```js
 registerSucess:boolean = false;

 createUserData(ff){
    this.us.createform(ff).subscribe((user:any)=>{
      console.log("Success register");
      this.registerSucess=true;
    });
  }
```

and in the tempalte:

```html
<form #ff="ngForm" *ngIf="!registerSucess">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="User Name" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.fname"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="age" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.age"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.sex"/> Male<br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser.sex"/> Female<br/><br/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" (click)="createUserData(ff.value)">
</form>

<h1 *ngIf="registerSucess"> Register Success :D </h1>
```

or you could use the variavle `user`instead of `registerSuccess`, might be simpler

Comment: form disappear when get message. I want rest form and show success message.

Comment: then just remove `*ngIf="!registerSucess"`from the <form>

Comment: I removed it but form value not reset I tried with `ff.reset()`

Comment: you should post a different question for this problem but a very simple (and ugly) solution would be this inside your subscribe:
`this.selectedUser: = {fname:null, age:  null, sex: null};`

Answer (score 0):

Create a string variable in `user.component.ts` to hold the message

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    message = '';
...
```

Add an element to the html to contain the message, I'll use a `<p>`. Double curly brackets `{{ }}` allow you to insert a variable from the component.

```html
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

Now simply updating the message in the component will update the html

```js
  createUserData(ff){
    this.message = "Creating User Data..."
    this.us.createform(ff).subscribe((user:any)=>{
      this.message = "Success!"
    });
  }
```

Comment: how to reset form.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
this.us.createform(ff).subscribe((user:any) => {
   console.log("Success Register")
});
```

The code in the 'subscribe' delta function is executed every time a response is received through the 'createform' function. So here you can input some sort of mechanism to trigger you popup.

You need a popup window to be shown, which comes down to what sort of UI components you are using. The popup can be written in your html, and only shown through a flag that you activate in the subscribe delta function, and then disable when pressing or closing the popup.

I'd recommend using something like bootstrap for UI components.